# Getting no results for select title, publisher name, type, and author names of each book that has two authors

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the details of book which has 2 authors and for that i wrote the following query.

```
SELECT BOOK.Book_Title
     , PUBLISHER.Publisher_Name
     , BOOK.Book_Type 
     , AUTHOR.Author_Last
     , AUTHOR.Author_First 
  FROM AUTHOR
     , WROTE
     , BOOK
     , PUBLISHER 
 WHERE AUTHOR.Author_Num = WROTE.Author_Num 
   AND WROTE.Book_Code = BOOK.Book_Code 
   AND BOOK.Publisher_Code = PUBLISHER.Publisher_Code
HAVING COUNT(WROTE.Book_Code) = 2;
```

But when i run it, i get 0 rows returned. Although data is available in the tables and there are several rows in which there are 2 authors against one book.

This is the schema on which i am applying the query.

[image]

Following is the data available in WROTE table which is a many-to-many relation for BOOK and AUTHOR table.

[image]

Please tell me where is the problem?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`. `JOIN`. `JOIN`.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Strawberry You changed the Query code, slightly I admit, so I reverted

Comment: @RiggsFolly I changed the fomatting, but not the meaning.

Comment: @Strawberry You removed the `()` I know they are irrelevant in real terms but any changes to code other than formatting is just dangerous

Comment: @Strawberry I dont believe I stated anything as FACT. You are right this is my and one other persons opinion.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to use JOIN on these 4 tables? Please modify my query with JOIN clause. Thanks

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry Agree with the _but I think it's a bit off to undo code that someone spent time_ But does that only apply to you, or does that [include me as well](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56147907/revisions)?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It only applies to me ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry HHAaaaaaa :) Ok, long as I know for the future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is incorrect because it has no GROUP BY section while you're trying to apply HAVING condition that assumes to have some grouped fields.

I'd like to use following query (MS SQL):

```
SELECT bk.Book_Title
     , pb.Publisher_Name
     , bk.Book_Type 
     , auth.Author_Last
     , auth.Author_First 
  FROM AUTHOR as auth
        join WROTE as wr on auth.Author_Num = wr.Author_Num
        join BOOK as bk on wr.Book_Code = bk.Book_Code
        join PUBLISHER as pb on bk.Publisher_Code = pb.Publisher_Code
where exists (SELECT 1 
                from  WROTE as wr_ex
                where wr_ex.Book_Code = wr.Book_Code
                group by wr_ex.Book_Code
                having count(1) = 2 )
```

There maybe a variation with a subquery that select Book_codes with 2 authors in FROM section that should be folowed by joining all other stuff